# Cannot convert value of type 'Range<Int>' to expected argument type 'Range<Index>' (aka 'Range<String.CharacterView.Index>')

Tags: string, swift, substring

I have a string here, which I am trying to substring.

```
let desc = "Hello world. Hello World."
var stringRange = 1..<5
desc.substringWithRange(stringRange)
```

However Swift gives me an error with this. What have I done wrong? I am using the new notation of the stringRange because it doesn't let me use the old one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Range` you have created does not have the correct type, it is inferred to be an `Int`. You need to create the range from the string itself:

```
let desc = "Hello world. Hello World."
let stringRange = desc.startIndex..<desc.startIndex.advancedBy(5)
let sub = desc[stringRange]
```

It's slightly more complex with `String`. Alternatively, go back to `NSString` and `NSRange`:

```
let range = NSMakeRange(0, 5)
let sub2 = (desc as NSString).substringWithRange(range)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `1..<5` is from type `Range<Int>`, while the method `substringWithRange` expects a value from type `Range<Index>`

```
let desc = "Hello world. Hello World."

var dd = desc.substringWithRange(desc.startIndex..<desc.startIndex.advancedBy(5))
```

You may apply  `advanceBy` to the `desc.startIndex` as well